# AudioUnit: access ComponentKernel properties from CocoaView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-audio, audiounit

I would like to **access my AudioUnit Component Kernel members** from an action method defined in the **cocoa view** of my AudioUnit Component :

```
- (IBAction)iaParam1Changed:(id)sender {
    float floatValue = [sender floatValue];
    NSAssert(AUParameterSet(mParameterListener, sender, &mParameter[0], (Float32)floatValue, 0) == noErr, @"[MyAudioUnit_CocoaView iaParam1Changed:] AUParameterSet()");
    if (sender == uiParam1Slider) {
        [uiParam1TextField setFloatValue:floatValue];
    } else {
        [uiParam1Slider setFloatValue:floatValue];
    }
}
```

(For instance, interact with stats computed on the signal...). But I don't know how to use the `AudioUnit mAU` member of the Cocoa View to get the Kernel (and then its members)... How would you do that? (Maybe i'm not supposed to do that?) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Define an AudioUnit custom property
- Access it from the cocoa view using AudioUnitGetProperty
- Reimplement the AUEffectBase::GetProperty method
- From GetProperty, access the kernels using the GetKernel(...) method
- Enjoy some tee